# How to convert label data with None values to OneHot using LabelBinarizer sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have label data that same of the values are `np.nan`. 
I want to convert the data to OneHot vector using [LabelBinarizer](http://scikitlearn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html), and the `np.nan` will convert to zero-array. 
But I get an error. I success to convert the data with [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) from `pandas` model. 
I can't use the `get_dummies` function because the train and the test data coming with different files and different time. I want to use `sklearn` model, for save it, and us the model latter.

Code for example:

```
In[11]: df = pd.DataFrame({'CITY':['London','NYC','Manchester',np.nan],'Country':['UK','US','UK','AUS']})
In[12]: df
Out[12]: 
         CITY Country
0      London      UK
1         NYC      US
2  Manchester      UK
3         NaN     AUS
In[13]: pd.get_dummies(df['CITY'])
Out[13]: 
   London  Manchester  NYC
0       1           0    0
1       0           0    1
2       0           1    0
3       0           0    0
In[14]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
        lb = LabelBinarizer()
In[15]: lb.fit_transform(df['CITY'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oshrib/.conda/envs/on_target/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-d0afb38b2695>", line 1, in <module>
    lb.fit_transform(df['CITY'])
  File "/home/oshrib/.conda/envs/on_target/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 307, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(y).transform(y)
  File "/home/oshrib/.conda/envs/on_target/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 276, in fit
    self.y_type_ = type_of_target(y)
  File "/home/oshrib/.conda/envs/on_target/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 288, in type_of_target
    if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
  File "/home/oshrib/.conda/envs/on_target/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 223, in unique
    return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
  File "/home/oshrib/.conda/envs/on_target/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 283, in _unique1d
    ar.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()
```

Comment: Why do not use `fillna` before?

Comment: Try `df = df.fillna('')` to replace the NaN values with an empty string (or whatever you want to put there). The problem comes from NaN being a float object and the other city labels are strings and hence different types.

Comment: In case I use `fillna`, the `LabelBinarizer` will create one more column for the `nan`, instead of create a zero-vector.

Comment: @oshribr you can delete it after, if you want.

Comment: @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia, this is what I done.